# How to set DHCP interface as default gateway in Debian 9

Tags: debian, networking

Debian 9 running on virtualbox. I have 2 adaptors, one NAT and the other Host Only. Here's my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
allow-hotplug enp0s3
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug enp0s8
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
    address 192.168.56.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.56.1
```

When I boot I get the 2nd interface as the default gateway, but I need the first.

Running this command manually solves it:

```
ip route change default via 10.0.2.3
```

**Assuming(?) that because this IP is DHCP generated (by virtualbox) how can I set this as the default route on boot?**

In case it's helpful, here's the output of `ip route show` (after that command)

```
default via 10.0.2.3 dev enp0s3 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.3
```

And here's the output of `ip addr show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b8:c5:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:c5ff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c8:d2:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.3/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec8:d2fb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `allow-hotplug` lines (you've got `auto` instead) and the `gateway` line (which sets the default gateway manually).

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Can't see the wood for the trees sometimes :-)